# how to download videos from a site using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

recently I`m watching some videos of CS 162 from  [this site](http://www.infocobuild.com/education/audio-video-courses/computer-science/CS162-Spring2014-Berkeley/lecture-02.html) 
and when I tried to find url of video I found out there is no url in inspect elements tab.
but I found the url of video in network tab. you can see this tab near inspect elements of site in opera.
I tried to get data of this tab using "requests" but It didn't turn out to be a clear url I was looking for.

Is there a way to gain data of network tab using python?
check [this site](https://bugthinking.com/how-to-save-a-video-from-jwplayer-website/) if you can't find network tab.

thanks;

Comment: r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

Answer (score 3):

I write this code base on your comment:

```
import requests
url = 'your site'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)   # your comment
print(r)
```

in the output there is a `<iframe>` tag which has a src of a .mp4.
I think you should grab that using `bs4` and then download the video you want.